# How to parse XML using python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an xml using python for create a result summary file. Below is my code and a snippet of xml, Like the below i have couple of sections with `<test>` and `</test>`

```xml
<test name="tst_case1">
  <prolog time="2013-01-18T14:41:09+05:30"/> 
  <verification name="VP5" file="D:/Squish/HMI_testing/tst_case1/test.py" type="properties" line="6"> 
    <result time="2013-01-18T14:41:10+05:30" type="PASS"> 
      <description>VP5: Object propertycomparisonof ':_QMenu_3.enabled'passed</description>        <description type="DETAILED">'false' and 'false' are equal</description> 
      <description type="object">:_QMenu_3</description> 
      <description type="property">enabled</description> 
      <description type="failedValue">false</description> 
    </result> 
  </verification>
  <epilog time="2013-01-18T14:41:11+05:30"/> 
</test>
```

What I want to get is,
in one `<test>` section how many PASS / FAIL is there.

With the below code its printing the total pass/Fail in the xml file.But i am interested in each section how many PASS/FAIL. can any boy tell me the procedure to fetchout this ?

```py
import sys
import xml.dom.minidom as XY

file = open("result.txt", "w")
tree = XY.parse('D:\\Squish\\squish results\\Results-On-2013-01-18_0241 PM.xml')
Test_name = tree.getElementsByTagName('test')
Test_status = tree.getElementsByTagName('result')
count_testname =0
passcount = 0
failcount = 0
Test_name_array = []
for my_Test_name in Test_name:
    count_testname = count_testname+1
    passcount = 0
    failcount = 0
    my_Test_name_final = my_Test_name.getAttribute('name')
    Test_name_array = my_Test_name_final
    if(count_testname > 1):
        print(my_Test_name_final)
        for my_Test_status in Test_status:
            my_Test_status_final = my_Test_status.getAttribute('type')
            if(my_Test_status_final == 'PASS'):
               passcount = passcount+1
            if(my_Test_status_final == 'FAIL'):
               failcount = failcount+1
            print(str(my_Test_status_final))
```

Comment: Do you have to use minidom? `xml.etree` would be an easier, more pythonic choice.

Answer (score 3):

I'd not use minidom for this task; the DOM API is very cumbersome, verbose, and not suited for searching and matching.

The Python library also includes the [`xml.etree.ElementTree` API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), I'd use that instead:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(r'D:\Squish\squish results\Results-On-2013-01-18_0241 PM.xml')
tests = dict()

# Find all <test> elements with a <verification> child:
for test in tree.findall('.//test[verification]'):
    passed = len(test.findall(".//result[@type='PASS']"))
    failed = len(test.findall(".//result[@type='FAIL']"))
    tests[test.attrib['name']] = {'pass': passed, 'fail': failed}
```

The above piece of code counts the number of passed and failed tests per `<test>` element and stores them in a dictionary, keyed to the `name` attribute of the `<test>` element.

I've tested the above code with Python 3.2 and the [full XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461128/xml-parsing-to-get-description-using-python-using-minidom) from another question you posted, which results in:

```
{'tst_Setup_menu_2': {'fail': 0, 'pass': 8}}
```

Comment: @BrijeshKrishnan: Provided the `<test>` elements are inside another element the answer should work; I've tested it (made a small correction).

Comment: error 
1. KeyError: "//result[@type='PASS']"
2. SyntaxError("cannot use absolute path on element")

Comment: What python version is this on? Note the `.` at the start of the XPath expression; it starts with `.//result`, not `//result`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the posting. i got it working using minidon.
still wish to see how can be solved using xml.etree.ElementTree

```
import sys
import xml.dom.minidom as XY

file = open("Result_Summary.txt", "w")
#tree = XY.parse('D:\\Squish\\squish results\\Results-On-2013-01-18_0241 PM.xml')
#print (str(sys.argv[1]))
tree = XY.parse(sys.argv[1])

Test_name = tree.getElementsByTagName('test')
count_testname =0

file.write('Test Name \t\t\t No:PASS\t\t\t No:FAIL\t \n\n')
for my_Test_name in Test_name:
    count_testname = count_testname+1
    my_Test_name_final = my_Test_name.getAttribute('name')
    if(count_testname > 1):
        #print(my_Test_name_final)
        file.write(my_Test_name_final)
        file.write('\t\t\t\t')
        my_Test_status = my_Test_name.getElementsByTagName('result')
        passcount = 0
        failcount = 0
        for my_Test_status_1 in my_Test_status:
            my_Test_status_final = my_Test_status_1.getAttribute('type')
            if(my_Test_status_final == 'PASS'):
               passcount = passcount+1
            if(my_Test_status_final == 'FAIL'):
               failcount = failcount+1
            #print(str(my_Test_status_final))
        file.write(str(passcount))
        #print(passcount)
        file.write('\t\t\t\t')
        file.write(str(failcount))
       # print(failcount)
        file.write('\n')

#print ('loop count: %d' %count_testname)
#print('PASS count: %s' %passcount)
#print('FAIL count: %s' %failcount)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not a standard module but well worth the effort of installing is [lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) especially if you want to do fast Xml parsing etc IMHO.

Without a full example of your results I guessed at what they would look like.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("results.xml")

count_result_type = etree.XPath("count(.//result[@type = $name])")

for test in tree.xpath("//test"):
    print test.attrib['name']
    print "\t# FAILS ", count_result_type(test, name="FAIL")
    print "\t# PASSES", count_result_type(test, name="PASS")
```

I generated the following running against my guess of your xml, which should give you an idea of what is happening.

```
tst_case1
    # FAILS  1.0
    # PASSES 1.0
tst_case0
    # FAILS  0.0
    # PASSES 1.0
tst_case2
    # FAILS  0.0
    # PASSES 1.0
tst_case3
    # FAILS  0.0
    # PASSES 1.0
```

What I like about [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is how expressive it can be, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Squish. You should check your squish folder under **\examples\regressiontesting**. There you can find a file called **xml2result2html.py**. Here you can find an example of converting squish test results into html.