# XML parsing to get description using python using minidom

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

Please suggest me what add additional code need to be added for the below code so that i can parse the below XML code to get the description.

```
<SquishReport version="2.1">
    <test name="HMI_testing">
        <prolog time="2013-01-22T18:59:43+05:30"/>
        <test name="tst_Setup_menu_2">
            <prolog time="2013-01-22T18:59:43+05:30"/>
            <verification line="7" type="" file="D:/Squish/HMI_testing/tst_Setup_menu_2/test.py" name="ECG is enabled">
                <result type="PASS" time="2013-01-22T18:59:45+05:30">
                    <description>Comparison</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">'1' and 'True' are equal</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">ECG is enabled</description>
                </result>
            </verification>
            <verification line="9" type="" file="D:/Squish/HMI_testing/tst_Setup_menu_2/test.py" name="ECG is enabled">
                <result type="PASS" time="2013-01-22T18:59:45+05:30">
                    <description>Comparison</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">'1' and 'True' are equal</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">ECG is enabled</description>
                </result>
            </verification>
            <verification line="11" type="" file="D:/Squish/HMI_testing/tst_Setup_menu_2/test.py" name="P1 is disabled">
                <result type="PASS" time="2013-01-22T18:59:45+05:30">
                    <description>Comparison</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">'0' and 'False' are equal</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">P1 is disabled</description>
                </result>
            </verification>
            <verification line="13" type="" file="D:/Squish/HMI_testing/tst_Setup_menu_2/test.py" name="P2 is disabled">
                <result type="PASS" time="2013-01-22T18:59:45+05:30">
                    <description>Comparison</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">'0' and 'False' are equal</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">P2 is disabled</description>
                </result>
            </verification>
            <verification line="15" type="" file="D:/Squish/HMI_testing/tst_Setup_menu_2/test.py" name="SPO2 is enabled">
                <result type="PASS" time="2013-01-22T18:59:45+05:30">
                    <description>Comparison</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">'1' and 'True' are equal</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">SPO2 is enabled</description>
                </result>
            </verification>
            <verification line="17" type="" file="D:/Squish/HMI_testing/tst_Setup_menu_2/test.py" name="CO2 is disabled">
                <result type="PASS" time="2013-01-22T18:59:45+05:30">
                    <description>Comparison</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">'0' and 'False' are equal</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">CO2 is disabled</description>
                </result>
            </verification>
            <verification line="19" type="" file="D:/Squish/HMI_testing/tst_Setup_menu_2/test.py" name="RESP is disabled">
                <result type="PASS" time="2013-01-22T18:59:45+05:30">
                    <description>Comparison</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">'0' and 'False' are equal</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">RESP is disabled</description>
                </result>
            </verification>
            <verification line="21" type="" file="D:/Squish/HMI_testing/tst_Setup_menu_2/test.py" name="TEMP is disabled">
                <result type="PASS" time="2013-01-22T18:59:45+05:30">
                    <description>Comparison</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">'0' and 'False' are equal</description>
                    <description type="DETAILED">TEMP is disabled</description>
                </result>
            </verification>
            <epilog time="2013-01-22T18:59:45+05:30"/>
        </test>
        <epilog time="2013-01-22T18:59:45+05:30"/>
    </test>
</SquishReport>
```

what i need to print is ECG is Enabled , NIBP is enabled etc..

the code i used is added below. I need to update the same code because of some dependency. need to add the code at print(Need to add the code here) mentioned in the code

```
import sys
import xml.dom.minidom as XY

file = open("Result_Summary.txt", "w")
tree = XY.parse('Results-On-2013-01-22_0659.xml')
#print (str(sys.argv[1]))
#tree = XY.parse(sys.argv[1])

Test_name = tree.getElementsByTagName('test')
count_testname =0
    file.write(' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n')
file.write('\tTest Name \t\t No Of PASS\t\t No Of FAIL\t\t\t Description\t\t \n')
file.write(' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n')
for my_Test_name in Test_name:
    count_testname = count_testname+1
    my_Test_name_final = my_Test_name.getAttribute('name')
    if(count_testname > 1):
        #print(my_Test_name_final)
        file.write(my_Test_name_final)
        file.write('\t\t\t')
        my_Test_status = my_Test_name.getElementsByTagName('result')
        passcount = 0
        failcount = 0
        for my_Test_status_1 in my_Test_status:
            my_Test_description = my_Test_name.getElementsByTagName('description')
            for my_Test_description_1 in my_Test_description:
                my_Test_description_final = my_Test_description_1.getAttribute('type')
                print(Need to add the code here)
                my_Test_status_final = my_Test_status_1.getAttribute('type')
                if(my_Test_status_final == 'PASS'):
                   passcount = passcount+1
                if(my_Test_status_final == 'FAIL'):
                   failcount = failcount+1
            #print(str(my_Test_status_final))
        file.write(str(passcount))
        #print(passcount)
        file.write('\t\t\t')
        file.write(str(failcount))
```

Ex

```
pected result

tst_Setup_menu_2     8        0        ECG Enabled
                                       p1 Enabled
                                       P2 Enabled etc
```

Comment: Use 'view source' before copying XML from Firefox; the browser displays the XML with some extra widgets that show up as `-` signs when you paste it here otherwise.

Comment: Please, try using ElementTree some more. You never provided me with enough information to help you with [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424426/how-to-parse-xml-using-python/14424570#14424570) where I showed you that ElementTree is far easier to use for these tasks.

Comment: Whats the dependency? You should really consider refactoring and possibly switching to another parsing library, because what you have is utterly unreadable.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters : i am using PythonWin 3.2.2 and it was not able to find lxml

Comment: @BrijeshKrishnan: ElementTree is part of Python, it comes bundled with Python 3.2 as `xml.etree.ElementTree`. The `lxml` package uses the same API but is not required for your tasks, I'd say.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\Lib\SITE-P~1\PYTHON~2\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 322, in RunScript
    debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=0)
  File "C:\Python32\Lib\SITE-P~1\PYTHON~2\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
    _GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
  File "C:\Python32\Lib\SITE-P~1\PYTHON~2\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 655, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "D:\Squish\HMI_testing\etree.py", line 13, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: No module named lxml

Comment: i have updated the XML by putting the whole thing

Comment: @BrijeshKrishnan: see my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424426/how-to-parse-xml-using-python/14424570#14424570), no `lxml` is used there. I note that your full XML has nested `test` elements, something you didn't tell me about before, which means I'll have to adjust that answer a little.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters : sorry by mistake i copied from lxml thats why the error.
import sys
import etree
print('HI')
file = open("Result_Summary.txt", "w")
tree = etree.parse("Results-On-2013-01-22_0659.xml")

count_result_type = etree.XPath("count(.//result[@type = $name])")

for test in tree.xpath("//test"):
    print test.attrib['name']
    print "\t# FAILS ", count_result_type(test, name="FAIL")
    print "\t# PASSES", count_result_type(test, name="PASS")

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: but its not giving any output

Comment: @BrijeshKrishnan: Let's discuss that answer by using comments there, shall we? I've tested the answer there against the XML posted here, and adjusted it a little for Python 3.2.

Comment: There are multiple `<description>` tags in each `<result>`. Do you only want to include the description from the last tag in each `<result>` tag? Or do you need all of them?

Comment: i want only the last one, the one with ECG is enabled, p1 enabled p2 enabled etc

Comment: @BrijeshKrishnan: but for each test, there are loads of results. There are 8 PASS results, each with descriptions. Do you want *one* line for that test (so `tst_Setup_menu_2\t\t\t8\t\t\t0\t\t\t[descriptions]`)? If so, what should `[descriptions]` look like? All the last detailed descriptions texts with commas in between?

Comment: it can be like below

tst_Setup_menu_2         8        0       ECG is enabled
                                          p1 is enabled
                                          p2 enabled...
tst_Setup_menu_1         etc      etc     list of description one in each line in the last colom

Comment: i have added expected result in my question

Comment: @BrijeshKrishnan: I've given them to you as one line in the file. It should be easy enough to change that to listing them one per line.

Comment: @BrijeshKrishnan: Expanded to match your output example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424426/how-to-parse-xml-using-python/14424570#14424570), please do use the ElementTree API for such tasks:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(r'D:\Squish\squish results\Results-On-2013-01-18_0241 PM.xml')

with open("Result_Summary.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(' {} \n\n'.format('-' * 101))
    output.write('\tTest Name \t\t No Of PASS\t\t No Of FAIL\t\t\t Description\t\t \n')
    output.write(' {} \n\n'.format('-' * 101))

    # Find all <test> elements with a <verification> child:
    for test in tree.findall('.//test[verification]'):
        # Collect passed and failed counts
        passed = len(test.findall(".//result[@type='PASS']"))
        failed = len(test.findall(".//result[@type='FAIL']"))
        # Collect all the *last* <description> elements of type DETAILED
        descriptions = test.findall(".//result/description[@type='DETAILED'][last()]")
        # write a line of information to the file, including first desc
        output.write('{0}\t\t\t{1}\t\t\t{2}\t\t\t{3}\n'.format(
            test.attrib['name'], passed, failed, descriptions[0].text))
        # write remaining descriptions
        for desc in descriptions[1:]:
            output.write('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t{0}\n'.format(desc.text))
```

Comment: last tab i am getting as <Element 'description' at 0x42ce438>

Comment: tst_Setup_menu_2   8   0   <Element 'description' at 0x42ce438>
         <Element 'description' at 0x42ce160>
         <Element 'description' at 0x42d5240>
         <Element 'description' at 0x42d5ef0>
         <Element 'description' at 0x42d75c0>
         <Element 'description' at 0x42d7b00>
         <Element 'description' at 0x42cc160>
         <Element 'description' at 0x42ccef0>

Comment: @BrijeshKrishnan: oops, sorry, that should be `.text` behind each element.

Comment: Although this might solve the problem, it doesn't really answer the question. Does it really deserve an accept in that case?

Comment: @MarkRansom: The conversation has been going for a more than a few questions now. The OP appeared to be confused as to the availability of ElementTree, and had trouble running previous answers using ET. Moreover, I usually *only* suggest accepting an answer when the OP a) thanks me for my help and b) has not yet accepted an answer before.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Also of considerable importance: using minidom (or the DOM API, full stop) to extract data from XML is akin to hitting your head repeatedly with a board, if you ask me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following looks for result nodes and then the descriptions contained within them. This prevents incorrect description nodes from being selected

```
import xml.dom.minidom
# str = your_string_from_the_question

doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(str)
for result in doc.getElementsByTagName("result"):
    for description in result.getElementsByTagName("description"):
        print description.firstChild.data
```

Gives

```
Comparison
'1' and 'True' are equal
ECG is enabled
....
```

The getElementsByName method returns a list of nodes (hence the looping). The line `result.getElementsByTagName("description")` returns the node `<description>Comparison</description>`. The text 'Comparison' is a text node in XML, hence you have to reference it with firstChild (to get the node) and data to get the text

[EDIT]

If you require the 3rd description (and you know it will always be the third) you could do this (untested)

```
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(str)
for result in doc.getElementsByTagName("result"):
    description_list = result.getElementsByTagName("description")
    if len(description_list.length >= 3):
        description[2].firstChild.data
```

Comment: thanks. that works. but a question here i am in need of only the third description. any provision to fetch only that "ECG is enabled
"?

Comment: when i put if len(my_Test_description >= 3): it gives error 
Traceback (most recent call last):

TypeError: unorderable types: NodeList() >= int()